# Site Satisfaction Survey questionnaire seems to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just tried to fill out the new Site Satisfaction Survey questionnaire (https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/). When being asked what to improve on Stack Overflow, I selected one option, then I was asked to rank my single choice. So I ranked it first, only to receive as answer that I should answer the question (in red).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging internally, it was determined this was the Site Satisfaction Survey. One of our research team had a call with the vendor we use for this survey and they have resolved the issue within their platform so it "no longer require survey respondents to select their answer in order to proceed in the survey when they've only selected one response in the previous question". So we did find and fix the issue. Thank you for reporting it.